# ElasticSearch 6.0.1 - SQL DISTINCT clause - NEST C#

Tags: c#, sql, elasticsearch, nest

I need to return JUST all categories DISTINCTS (without repeat any) from a document using NEST.

In SQL it looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category  
  FROM Log  
  ORDER BY Category ASC
```

Inside ElasticSearch I do this way:

```
GET log/_search
{
  "size":"0",
  "aggs" : {
  "alias_category" : {
  "terms" : { "field" : "category.keyword" }
  }
  }
}
```

How can I do that using NEST?

```
public ICollection<string> SelectAllCategoriesDistinct(ElasticClient client)
    {
        var searchResponse = client.Search<LogElasticSearch>(s => s
                                        .Query(q => q
                                            .Terms(t => t
                                                .Field(f => f.Category)
                                            )
                                        )
                                     );
        return (ICollection<string>)searchResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. Is not a elegant way, but I found in the elastico site (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/c-nest-best-way-of-accessing-properties-of-iaggregate-object/85384/2) and I did this way:

```
public ICollection<string> SelectAllCategoriesDistinct(ElasticClient client)
    {
        var searchResponse = 
            client.Search<LogElasticSearch>(s => s
                .Size(0)
                .Aggregations(agg => agg
                    .Terms("categories", t => t
                        .Field("category.keyword")
                    )                  
                )
            );
       
        var aggregation = searchResponse.Aggregations.Values;
        var listOfCategories = new List<string>();

        if (searchResponse.Aggregations.Values.FirstOrDefault().GetType() == typeof(BucketAggregate))
        {
            foreach (IBucket bucket in ((BucketAggregate)aggregation.FirstOrDefault()).Items)
            {
                if (bucket.GetType() == typeof(KeyedBucket<object>))
                {
                    var valueKey = ((KeyedBucket<object>)bucket).Key;
                    listOfCategories.Add(valueKey.ToString());
                }
            } 
        }

        return listOfCategories.OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
    }
```

If someone knows a better way to do it, help me to improve, but that way it reaches the goal.

Comment: You can use `searchResponse.Aggregations.Terms("categories")` to get the terms aggregation results (buckets, etc.). The `.Aggregations` property on the search response has a convenient method for getting each type of aggregation from the response

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/composite-aggregation-usage.html) to fetch all the terms. In contrast to the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-aggregation-usage.html), the composite aggregation supports pagination, so multiple requests can be made if there are a *lot* of terms to fetch

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool); 
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    
    var categories = new List<string>();

    GetAllCategories(client, categories);
    
    // do something with the categories
    foreach(var category in categories)
        Console.WriteLine(category);
}

private static void GetAllCategories(IElasticClient client, List<string> categories, CompositeKey after = null)
{
    // number of terms to fetch in each request
    var size = 10_000;
    
    var response = client.Search<LogElasticSearch>(s => s
        .Size(0)
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Composite("categories", c => c
                .After(after)
                .Size(size)
                .Sources(so => so
                    .Terms("category", t => t
                        .Field("category.keyword")
                        .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var compositeAgg = response.Aggregations.Composite("categories");
    var buckets = compositeAgg.Buckets;

    foreach (var bucket in buckets)
    {
        if (bucket.Key.TryGetValue("category", out string category))
        {
            categories.Add(category);
        }
    }

    // there may be more
    if (buckets.Count == size)
    {
        GetAllCategories(client, categories, compositeAgg.AfterKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Russ! I forgot to specify ... I'm using elasticsearch in version 6.0.1. I think .Composite does not work in this version.

Comment: @WeslleyRufinodeLima I think you'll need to just use a terms aggregation with a large size to cover all of the distinct tags.